# Как выглядит скрипт для запуска "python manage py runserver" на языке BASH в entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Мне нужно в entrypoint.sh прописать скрипт по запуску локального сервера Django, когда запускается контейнер.
команда "python manage.py runserver".
Как это будет выглядеть в BASH?